# change line in file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that does the following:

1. Open a text file.
2. Find a line that matches the following pattern:

   ```
   public interface $A extends InterfaceName
   ```

   and change it to:

   ```
   public interface $A extends InterfaceName<$A>
   ```
3. Save the file.

Comment: So the only difference is a single space at the beginning of a line? And what $A can stand for - text with no spaces?

Comment: More importantly is there something you have tried?

Comment: Is `$A` literal text in your file? A PowerShell variable? A generic placeholder for arbitrary interface names?

Answer (score 2):

You can read the data from a file using `Get-Content`, search for the match and replace it using `Foreach-Object` and `-replace`, and then write it back to the file using `Set-Content`. The regular expression can be used to add the code that you need:

```
# Get the content from a file
Get-Content 'C:\path_to_your_file.txt' | 
# Get replace each line if it matches the pattern
ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "(public interface (\S+) extends InterfaceName)", ' $1<$2>' } |
# Save the changes back to the file
Set-Content 'C:\path_to_your_file.txt'
```

Comment: my bad, I changed the question